# Tableau (Data > X days)

Tags: tableau-api

I'm a novice to Tableau, not going to lie. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to pull data from a table that's greater than thirty days old.

Basically, I have a set of work orders, and I'm just trying to get the count of the total work orders that are open AND older than thirty days. How would I go about doing this? I feel like it's a lot simpler than I'm trying to make it out to be.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a calculated field and filter on that.

1. right click on your date field choose Create/Calculated Field
2. Use this formula, with [Date] being your date field: `TODAY() - [Date]` or, more flexible `DATEDIFF("day" , [Date], TODAY())`
3. give it a name eg. datediff
4. drag and drop datediff to the filter shelf, choose "all values" and set the range, for you 0-30

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your date filed as a filter and choosing the relative filter format.[image: Similar to this]